# ORA-06502 numeric or vlaue error building string for clob

Tags: sql, oracle, clob

I've spent all day looking at existing StackOverflow questions and answers on this, but so far nothing has worked.

I think my problem is slightly different to everyone elses.

I am building a JSON string based on a `SELECT` from the database. This needs to be able to handle 50k+ records. I am using 11g but it will be deployed on 10g as well.

I am using a `CLOB` to store this return json string, because it has a capacity of 4GB. However, I keep getting the error: `ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error`. Previously I was getting this error when appending a `varchar` onto my `clob`, for example `returnString := returnString || "some text;` so I believe it was casting the clob to a varchar and causing this. Since then, I've gotten rid of anywhere I think a cast could be occuring, by using `dbms_log.append()`

Here is my PL/SQL:

```
declare

  v_person_code ca_mips_queue.person_code%type;
  v_person_type ca_mips_queue.person_type%type;

  cursor cur_mips is
    select person_code,person_type from ca_mips_queue 
    where terminal_code = :terminal_code and (download_stage='1' or download_stage = '2');

  returnString clob;
  v_isFirst boolean := TRUE;

begin

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(returnString, true);
  dbms_lob.open(returnString, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
  dbms_lob.append(returnString, '{"items":[');

  for person_rec in cur_mips
  loop
      v_person_code := person_rec.person_code;
      v_person_type := person_rec.person_type;

      update ca_mips_queue
      set download_stage = '2'
      where terminal_code = :terminal_code
      and person_code = v_person_code
      and person_type = v_person_type;

      if v_isFirst then
          dbms_lob.append(returnString, '{"person_code": "');
          v_isFirst := FALSE;
      else
          dbms_lob.append(returnString,  ',{"person_code": "');
      end if;

      dbms_lob.append(returnString, v_person_code);
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, '", "person_type": "');
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, v_person_type);
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, '"}');

      dbms_output.put_line(length(returnString));

  end loop;

  commit;

  dbms_lob.append(returnString, ']}');
  :result := returnString;

  dbms_lob.close(returnString);

  :status_code := 200;

  exception 
    when others then
      :status_code := 500;
      :exception := SQLERRM;
      DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(:exception);

end;
```

Notice I am printing out the size of `returnString` on each loop using `dbms_output.put_line(length(returnString));`
Here is the output (or the last few) of that:

```
43933
43976
44019
44062
44105
44148
44191
44234
44277
44320
44363
44406
44449
44492
44535
44578
44621
44664
44707
44750
44793
44836
44879
44922
44965
45008
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error
```

So it looks like its getting into trouble at around 45008 bytes (450kb?).

How can this be if a `clob` has a limit of 4GB?

Comment: Perhaps the problem is `length()`.  That takes a character argument, not a CLOB.  Try `dbms_lob.getlength()`.

Comment: How is your `result` bind variable defined? It might help to temporarily remove the `when others` so you can see the full error stack, including the line number that throws the error. Or re-raise it, or use the error formatting tools... I'd guess that variable is too small, but it would be helpful to be able to see if it is that assignment that is failing.

Comment: No it's not 'length()'. That is there for debug only. If I remove it, I get the same error.

Comment: @GordonLinoff - That is incorrect. At least since Oracle 10, `length()` accepts a CLOB argument. Documentation is easy to check. https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions076.htm

Comment: Since the code is running fine for many rows, and then it breaks when it is not supposed to... I would suspect invalid data in the database. You should be able to find out where the code fails (on what input) - perhaps by ordering the rows by person_code and outputting person_code instead of length, to see the last row where things were OK - then look at the next row to see if the data is valid. Good luck!

Comment: But why are you convinced it's erroring inside the loop? If you don't want to change the exception handler, can you at least out another debug before and after the `result` assignment line? I'd still like to know how that variable is declared...

Comment: Alex, I am using APEX as my REST server, and I have `:result` defined as URI/OUT/STRING.

Comment: Is it possible to do a select and an update in the same command, and return the result of the select in APEX? Because that would solve all my problems!

Comment: Looks like String isn't  big enough - I guess it's 32k? Not my area though; docs only seem to refer to CLOB as a media type. You can't update and query in a single SQL statement. How about a function that updates (which is normally avoided) and then returns the CLOB? I don't know APEX at all though. Good luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran the code by doing some slight changes and it seems to be working beyond the 450kb.

```
declare

  v_person_code ca_mips_queue.person_code%type;
  v_person_type ca_mips_queue.person_type%type;

  cursor cur_mips is
    select person_code,person_type from ca_mips_queue;

  returnString clob;
  v_isFirst boolean := TRUE;

begin

  dbms_lob.createtemporary(returnString, true);
  dbms_lob.open(returnString, DBMS_LOB.LOB_READWRITE);
  dbms_lob.append(returnString, '{"items":[');

  for person_rec in cur_mips
  loop
      v_person_code := person_rec.person_code;
      v_person_type := person_rec.person_type;

      if v_isFirst then
          dbms_lob.append(returnString, '{"person_code": "');
          v_isFirst := FALSE;
      else
          dbms_lob.append(returnString,  ',{"person_code": "');
      end if;

      dbms_lob.append(returnString, v_person_code);
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, '", "person_type": "');
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, v_person_type);
      dbms_lob.append(returnString, '"}');

      dbms_output.put_line(length(returnString));

  end loop;

  commit;

  dbms_lob.append(returnString, ']}');
--  :result := returnString;

  dbms_lob.close(returnString);

  :status_code := 200;

end;
```

Here is the output for the last few rows.

```
146471
146545
146639
146726
146803
146880
146958
147036
147116
147194
147267
147350
147419
147489
147559
147630
147706
147778
147850
147923
147995
148068
148135
148203
148278
148360
148437
148510
148585
148666
148746
148821
148899
148985
149060
149137
149211
149305

Statement processed.
```

Please note that I have commented the following line.

```
:result := returnString;
```

So I would say that the problem does not reside in the loop as Alex Poole has already pointed out.

Can you please try these changes in your code.

Comment: Hi, yes it works with the `:result` commented out. For some reason it won't convert. The problem is that I need to return the JSON via the result. Is there any way I can properly return the JSON without this error? Thanks.

Comment: Can you try this. Change the source type of your Get Handler from PLSQL  to Query. Now instead of the PLSQL just type your query in Source. select person_code, person_type from ca_mips_queue

Comment: Yes, that works. The purpose of this SQL is to do 3 things: The `SELECT`, the `UPDATE` and `return the result of the SELECT`. I'm a beginner at database stuff so I think I'll just 2 endpoints. One to get the `SELECT` and a second one to do the `UPDATE`. Unless they can be done in one? (which like I said, is what I was attempting here)

Comment: Can you split it into two separate web services. The first one can do the update part and the second one can be the Select

Comment: ye I think the only option is to split them into 2 endpoints, unfortunately.

Comment: I'm marking this as the answer as it directed me to the correct line that was causing the issue. My solution was to separate the 2 REST calls to 2 different endpoints.